# MATLAB code for unusual sequence

Tags: matlab

I have the equation

```
x = b/n [-(N/2), - ((N-1)/2), - ((N-2)/2), ..., 0, ..., ((N-2)/2), ((N-1)/2), ((N)/2)]
```

And I have been trying to code this into MATLAB I have used the following code

```
x=(b/N)*(-(N/2):(N/2))
```

and also tried

```
x=(b/N)*(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2))
```

**BUT** instead of subtracting one each time and giving the value, it subtracts to the next integer value. Therefore giving N+1 elements in the answer instead of 2N+1 elements.

i.e.

```
b =2 N=4
```

MATLAB will give the answer of:

```
-1  -0.5   0   0.5    1
```

whereas the answer I want is

```
-1,  -0.75,   -0.5,    -0.25,     0,    0.25,    0.5,     0.75,     1
```

Comment: does this work? `-b/2:b/2/n:b/2`

Comment: Your step is `b/(2*n)`, not 1.

Comment: What do you mean @Bentoy13

Comment: @user3190506: He means you should use `x = b/N/2 * (-N:N)` instead of what you have in your question.

Comment: @user3190506 You have two choices: either you do as RodyOldenhuis says, or you do as Guddu says. The point is to have the right step. In the example in the OP, you want a final step of 0.25, so either you specify a step of 0.25 (Guddu's answer), or or you leave the default step of 1 and divide after (Rody's comment). As you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
-b/2:b/2/n:b/2
```

Comment: then pls accept the answer as correct so that i can get points :P